# How to display a dropdown in spring MVC3(form:select path) with resonsebody json data

Tags: jquery, spring, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate(many to one) relationship:

```
    @Entity
    public class City implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String description;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="state_id")
        private State state;...
    }
```

Model for cities:

```
    @Entity
    public class State {    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        private String description;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy="state")

        private List<City> city=new ArrayList<>();...
    }
```

model for customers:

```
    @Entity
    public class Customer implements Serializable {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5442590361339242648L;
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private long id;
        @NotEmpty
        private String firstname;
        @NotEmpty
        private String lastname;
        @NotEmpty
        private String phone;
        @NotEmpty
        private String address;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="city_id")
        private City city;
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn (name="state_id")
        private State state;
        @NotEmpty
        private String zipcode;
        @NotEmpty
        @Email
        private String email;
        private int status;
        private Date createdate;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
        private List<Account> account = new ArrayList<Account>();...
    }

    in my controller i've a method:

    @RequestMapping(value = "/city", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody
        List<City> findCities(
                @RequestParam(value = "stateId", required = true) long city,
                Model model) {

            List<City> myCity = cityDao.getCityState(city);

            return myCity;
        }
```

i've a jquery function :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#state').change(function() {
            $.getJSON('${findCitiesURL}',{stateId : $(this).val(),ajax : 'true'},
                function(data) {
                    var html = '<option value="">City</option>';
                        var len = data.length;
                            for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                html += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">'+ data[i].description+ '</option>';
                            }
                            html += '</option>';
                            $('#city').html(html);
                            });
                            });
                    });
</script>
```

My question is how can i replace in jquery the code which display cities with codes like form:select path...

**i'm not able to save data in my database**

Comment: Your question is quite unclear, what is your problem: "i'm not able to save data in my database" or "how can i replace in jquery the code which display cities with codes like form:select path"

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is **displaying HTML elements should have nothing to do with Hibernate**. You should not confuse presentation (HTML) with persistence (Hibernate).

To display dropdown of cities, Spring `<form:select>` tag can be used like this:

```
<form:select path="city" items="${cities}" itemLabel="description" itemValue="id" />
```

`${cities}` refers model attribute of a collection of City objects which you should pass on your Controller. itemLabel and itemValue sets what label / value should be used to populate the HTML `<option>` tag

Hibernate (persistence) comes into play when your controller have to fetch a collection of cities from database.

Comment: Thank u Raph and gerrytan for your inputs, display using jquery is working fine. i've problem when i want to persist data using hibernate. hibernate expect an object, in my dropdown(select option) using jquery,  when i try to save it takes option value, which cannot be persist to the database. I want a way to save an object instead of option value

Comment: But your question says "How to display a dropdown in spring MVC3(form:select path) with resonsebody json data"